# Getting an INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE Error and connection to website was reset

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web

The connection to the website was reset.
Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE

I have a C# web application running on our internal IIS 10 Server and the site uses Windows Authentication.  Our networking team setup everything needed to get to the site from the Internet.  I get the above error when connecting from the Internet and have the site listed in Local Sites.

I have users with laptops that sometimes work in the office and on the road.  So, we've added the url to Security - Local Sites so they aren't required to enter a login an password each time they go to the site.  This works fine until they hit the road where they get the above error.

If I remove the site from Local sites or added it to trusted sites, it works.  It works if they use Chrome, but not IE or Edge.  It also works if the VPN in, but they don't want to do that.

The message is very vague and I've tried a variety of things based on research I've been doing, but no luck.  One suggestion was to setup the Developers tools and capture the error, but this also proved to be of no value, unless I'm doing something wrong.

The message returns quickly, so it's not timing out.  I've also checked Event Logs and not finding any related messages.

I've tested this using different Custom Security Levels - Automatic Login with Current User, etc.

Please let me know if you have other suggestions or if I can supply additional information.

VS 2017, C#, IIS 10, .Net 4.6

Comment: It might be related to security header as described in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/888107/72332